# how to open twitter hash Tag Link in webview?

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I am making an android app in which i have to show Hash Tag  link of twitter But when i load this in our customized  webview it will open in the default browser.Can you help me how to open this in the web view rather then in the default Browser?

Link is:  **https://mobile.twitter.com/search/%23nokia**

Thanks...

```
    WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient()
    {
    /* Override page so it's load on my view only */
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
    // This line we let me load only pages inside Firstdroid Webpage
    if ( url.contains("firstdroid") == true )
    /* Load new URL Don't override URL Link */
    return false;

    // Return true to override url loading (In this case do nothing).
    return true;
    }
    };


    // Get Web view
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.WebView ); //This is the id you gave
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); //Zoom Control on web (You don't need this
    //if ROM supports Multi-Touch
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true); //Enable Multitouch if supported by ROM
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);

    // Load URL
    Log.v("", ""+web2);
    mWebView.loadUrl(web2);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v("", "EXECUTED");
    //website.this.finish();
    Intent ii = new Intent(getParent(), Socialsites.class);
    TabGroupActivity parentActivity3 = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();



    // ii.putExtra("WEB", six.get(arg2));





    parentActivity3.startChildActivity("bb", ii);
    }

});
```

Comment: can you paste your code here?

Comment: have a look at my code I have updated my question my url is in variable web2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write load.loadUrl(url) inside the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() as:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sue you have the permissions to access Internet

**In Manifest.**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**xml layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

**and to load your URL**

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("https://mobile.twitter.com/search/%23nokia");
```

Comment: I have done all the stuff previous but this is opening in the default browser and hide my tabs and other views which I have added in the same layout.

Comment: have a look at my code I have updated my question my url is in variable web2

Answer (score 0):

How about you use:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
{
    view.loadUrl("https://mobile.twitter.com/searches");
    needReload = true;
    return true;
}
```

And then you overload the function onPageFinished as:

```
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        progess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if(needReload){
            view.loadUrl("javascript:location.search = \"q=%23nokia\"");
            needReload = false;
        }
    }
```

It will reload the page with a search for nokia term.
You can replace nokia by :

```
    view.loadUrl("javascript:location.search = \"q=%23" +searchTerms +"\"");
```

To get something more flexible.